# AngularJS - When opening controller in new browser window, clicks on the child window randomly triggers events on the parent window

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a requirement that I am trying to implement as follows - 
I have an audit log page which has a button to display the logs on a new browser window, while continuing to do other stuff on the application open in the main window. 
We use ui-router and angularjs (1.6). Below is my code -

Route to the controller -

```
 .state('auditlog', {
        url: '/auditlog',
        templateUrl: 'app/system/audit/audit-log.html',
        controller: 'AuditLogController',
        controllerAs: 'al'
    })
```

On the click event of a button in a different controller, I have the following code -

```
unDockEventsPanel(event) {
    let location = this.$state.href('auditlog');
    this.$window.open(location, '', 'scrollbars=no,fullscreen=yes,toolbar=no');
}
```

and the HTML -

```
<i class="Icon-MoveOut Icon-Large icon-btn" ng-click="eventsPanelVM.unDockEventsPanel($event)">
```

Now, when I click on the "MoveOut" button the unDockEventsPanel() method gets called and a new window is opened with the contents of the controller/template in the route definition "auditlog".

The problem I'm facing however is, any operation I perform on the child window is randomly triggering something else on the parent window and vice versa. For eg. When I click on a select button in the child window, the select opens up on the child, but also, on the parent the a text box comes into focus like it would if I had clicked it. Likewise, when I click a select on the parent, a different control on the child gets highlighted.

I can see that a new instance of the application/controller is not created on the child and hence there is an overlap of the controls and events between the two. But I'm not able to figure out how to isolate the two.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This only happens on my localhost. When I deploy it and have several windows, they don't overlap.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is related to the use of '$state'

```
let location = this.$state.href('auditlog');
this.$window.open(location, '', 'scrollbars=no,fullscreen=yes,toolbar=no');
```

from the [angular-ui github wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki)

> When a state is activated, its templates are automatically inserted into the ui-view of its parent state's template.

I would suggest trying to avoid the use of $state by using plain old Javascript to do the new window navigation

```
window.open("{yourURL}/auditlog", 'scrollbars=no,fullscreen=yes,toolbar=no');
```

Comment: I tried this approach. But ultimately this.$state.href('auditlog'); does just return a string similar to "#/auditlog" so, finally I am just passing a string to window.open().
I still commented out the $state code altogether and hardcoded the url string similar to your above example. But it did not fix the problem.